# Error with newest version of Xcode using Firebase?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I recently updated to the newest version of `Xcode (7.3.1)` and with the use of `Firebase` in project I receive this error:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-
>
> > F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
> >     ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES)
> >     cannot be used together

However, I am still able to build and run the project on the simulator.  I've tried deleting unnecessary libraries inside the framework paths, but it still gives me this error.  Does it have to do with the Firebase frameworks I am using?

Comment: I haven't yet done any project with the Firebase but the warning description is telling that you need to update setting in the project's build settings you need to search for `-bundle` and if there is some value in this property then search for `bitcode` and if there is `yes` you need to set it to `no`. This will silence the warning as per my knowledge.

Comment: I tried that too I think, I'm not sure if I did it correctly but under Build Options inside Build Settings, I changed Enable Bitcode to No yet the error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Set Build Setting-> Bitcode = NO;(See Below image)

[image]

Comment: I tried that and it didn't seem to remove the error:/

Comment: after which type error display?
how to add firebase means (pod install or framework)?